# Rails partial index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following hash structure:

```
@elements = {"0" => {:image => "asd", :title => "asd"},"1" => {..}..}
```

and I'm trying to get the values image and title for each element inside the partial.

What I'm using to pass the hash to the partial

`render partial: 'single_partial', collection: @elements,:as => :element`

What I'd expect the value of element to be inside the partial

`{:image => "asd", :title => "asd"}`

What the value of element actually is

`{"0" => {:image => "asd", :title => "asd"}}`

I could access it as `element[:index]`, but I cant find anything about the index. Is there another way of passing only the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest would probably be:

```
render partial: 'single_partial', collection: @elements.values,as: :element
```

Alternatively you could access it inside the partial as:

```
element.first.second
```

Comment: Thank you. I've only tried with `.value`. What would the structure of the `@elements` have to be to be like to behave like a relation returned from a database query? So i can access elements inside a collection like `element.image` instead of `element[:image]`.

Comment: It would have to be an array or array-like: `@elements = [ {:image => "asd", :title => "asd"}, {..}, {...}, ..}`. Where are you getting the elements from?

Comment: I m parsing an HTML page.

Comment: Why don't you post the code, possibly create a new question.

Comment: Well, your answer solved my problem. It s working like that.